# sqlalchemy on postgresql resets search_path in session after calling get_bind() -- is this expected?

Tags: python, postgresql, session, sqlalchemy

Consider the following example:

```
import unittest
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:5432/dbname')
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

def print_search_path(label, session):
print("{} -- search path: {}".format(label, session.execute('show search_path').fetchall()[0][0]))

class TestSearchPath(unittest.TestCase):

    def create_schema(self):
        sql = """\
        create schema if not exists test_schema;

        drop table if exists test_schema.foo;

        create table test_schema.foo(
            foo_id serial primary key 
          , name varchar unique
        );

        insert into test_schema.foo(name) values ('foo1');
        insert into test_schema.foo(name) values ('foo2');
        """
        print(sql)
        engine.execute(sql)

    def drop_schema(self):
        sql = "drop schema test_schema cascade;"
        print(sql)
        engine.execute(sql)

    def setUp(self):
        self.create_schema()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.drop_schema()

    def test_search_path(self):

        session = session_maker()
        try:
            print_search_path('beginning', session)
            session.execute('set search_path to test_schema')
            print_search_path('after initialize path', session)

            # execute a read
            session.get_bind().execute("select * from test_schema.foo where name='foo2'")
            print_search_path('before commit', session)
            session.commit()
            print_search_path('after commit', session)
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
```

I get the following output:

```
beginning -- search path: "$user", public
after initialize path -- search path: test_schema
before commit -- search path: test_schema
after commit -- search path: "$user", public
```

So this is surprising to me so maybe I have a misconception.  Naively, I would have expected the schema to remain `test_schema` for the entire program; however after the commit, it appears that the search path is reset to `public`.

My question is

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. If it is not, is there a way to ensure that session always has same search_path throughout it's lifetime?

Thanks
Ryan

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it appears that the sessionmaker() initialization automatically 'flushes' sessions, so if you want to reference your session again later in the program you may want to try adding autoflush=False to the argument of sessionmaker() in line 6. 
That is, try replacing line 6 with:

```
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine,autoflush=False)
```

Hope this helps!

I used the documentation on [this](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html) page, in particular referring to the first code chunk referring to global scope and the listing of arguments.

EDIT: This approach did not work. As was noted in the comments, autoflush refers to something else. The same documentation page also shows expire_on_commit=True is auto-set unless otherwise specified, so my new answer is to replace the original code snippet I suggested with:

```
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine,expire_on_commit=False)
```

Comment: hmm.  I tried your suggestion and I still get the same behavior as above.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still getting the hang of psql. Did you try putting autoflush=False in the session_maker() argument under test_search_path?

Comment: I think you're mixing autoflush with something else. It controls when changes held in the session are flushed to the database.

Comment: Thank you Ilja. After rechecking the documentation there is also a parameter called expire_on_commit that is automatically set to True unless otherwise specified. Perhaps it would be worth using that in the original sessionmaker() call rather than my misplaced suggestion of using autoflush?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @mmurray -- I just gave it a try and unfortunately it didn't change the behavior.  I'm not entirely sure that the documentation addresses this particular issue.  I'm a bit worried that what I've observed is unexpected behavior -- I was hoping someone would know what the issue is (probably on my end).